# Http interceptor is mistakenly applied to sibling modules in Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, interceptor, angular-module

I'm having the following module structure:

[image: diagram]

Unfortunately the HTTP interceptor which I provide in `core.module.ts` is also applied to the HTTP client in the `translation.module.ts`. My core module looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DefaultLayoutComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: BASE_API_URL, useValue: environment.api },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BaseUrlInterceptor, multi: true }
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, RouterModule, HttpClientModule],
  exports: [DefaultLayoutComponent]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

My translation module has the following code:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TranslationLoader implements TranslocoLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getTranslation(lang: string) {
    return this.http.get<Translation>(`/assets/i18n/${lang}.json`);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [HttpClientModule, TranslocoModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: TRANSLOCO_CONFIG,
      useValue: translocoConfig({
        availableLangs: ['en-US', 'de-CH', 'fr-CH', 'it-CH'],
        defaultLang: 'en-US',
        // Remove this option if your application doesn't support changing language in runtime.
        reRenderOnLangChange: true,
        prodMode: environment.production
      })
    },
    { provide: TRANSLOCO_LOADER, useClass: TranslationLoader }
  ]
})
export class TranslationModule {}
```

Both modules are used in my app module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [AppRoutingModule, CoreModule, TranslationModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The translation module loads some JSON files which don't have the correct URL, because the `BaseUrl` interceptor is applied. Somebody has an idea how to deal with this?

What I don't want is a workaround like only conditionally apply the base url within the interceptor or checking for some custom header.

Comment: I'm not sure you *can* have different interceptors per module like that, because every module uses the same `HttpClientModule` instance, and *that* instance will receive interceptors from all loaded modules. You'd either need to provide a new HttpClientModule instance somehow, or if you'd like you could just use a basic `fetch` call which would avoid the `HttpClient`(and its interceptors) altogether.

Comment: Thank you @Badashi for your reply. I've found the following note in the documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor#usage-notes
Maybe this helps me somehow, but I'm unsure how to apply this.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are providing **TranslationLoader** loader seems strange.  You are both providing it in the module and have the **providedIn** value set to *forRoot* in the **Injectable** decorator.  It could be by doing things the way you currently are that it's creating some confusing with the Dependency Injector.  I could especially see a problem if somebody injects it without the *TRANSLOCO_LOADER* token - exactly how it would know which **HttpClientModule** to use?

So try picking a method and either remove it in providers, or remove the **providedIn** parameter from the decorator and only inject it using an injection token.

Comment: This also happens if I move the TranslationLoader in it's own module. I've asked another question regarding to this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67355970/separate-httpclient-instances-per-module-in-angular